# Shortening a long nested subquery (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

The following subquery successfully returns the count of distinct segments for segments 1-8.

However the query runs slowly...
Anyone can help me make this query more efficient?

```
SELECT 
(  SELECT SUM (COUNT (DISTINCT segment1))
            FROM gl_code_combinations
           WHERE enabled_flag = 'Y' AND chart_of_accounts_id = 50181
        GROUP BY segment1)
          unique_segment1,
       (  SELECT SUM (COUNT (DISTINCT segment2))
            FROM gl_code_combinations
           WHERE enabled_flag = 'Y' AND chart_of_accounts_id = 50181
        GROUP BY segment2)
          unique_segment2,                 
          (  SELECT SUM (COUNT (DISTINCT segment3))
            FROM gl_code_combinations
           WHERE enabled_flag = 'Y' AND chart_of_accounts_id = 50181
        GROUP BY segment3)
          unique_segment3,
                 (  SELECT SUM (COUNT (DISTINCT segment4))
            FROM gl_code_combinations
           WHERE enabled_flag = 'Y' AND chart_of_accounts_id = 50181
        GROUP BY segment4)
          unique_segment4,
                 (  SELECT SUM (COUNT (DISTINCT segment5))
            FROM gl_code_combinations
           WHERE enabled_flag = 'Y' AND chart_of_accounts_id = 50181
        GROUP BY segment5)
          unique_segment5,
                 (  SELECT SUM (COUNT (DISTINCT segment6))
            FROM gl_code_combinations
           WHERE enabled_flag = 'Y' AND chart_of_accounts_id = 50181
        GROUP BY segment6)
          unique_segment6,
          (  SELECT SUM (COUNT (DISTINCT segment7))
            FROM gl_code_combinations
           WHERE enabled_flag = 'Y' AND chart_of_accounts_id = 50181
        GROUP BY segment7)
          unique_segment7,
          (  SELECT SUM (COUNT (DISTINCT segment8))
            FROM gl_code_combinations
           WHERE enabled_flag = 'Y' AND chart_of_accounts_id = 50181
        GROUP BY segment8)
          unique_segment8
  FROM DUAL;
```

here is a screenshot of the expected output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmHiw.png

Comment: Have a look at the [Analytic Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174). The [FIRST](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641) function may also help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT segment1),
       COUNT(DISTINCT segment2),
       . . .
FROM gl_code_combinations
WHERE enabled_flag = 'Y' AND chart_of_accounts_id = 50181
```